# Phaser Module Pattern and Sprites

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm working with Phaser and I'm using the module pattern, creating a module that has a prototype of `Object.create(Phaser.Sprite.prototype)` and creating an instance of that in the main module.

The problem is the sprite seems to be created in the main module in the create function but the image of the sprite is not loading and I can't find the problem or set the image.

Thanks so much!!

In Player.js:

```
// doenst work at all with game.load... on top
//game.load.spritesheet('playersheet', 'resources/data/foo.png', 64, 64);
Player = function(game, x, y){
    game.load.spritesheet('playersheet', 'resources/data/foo.png', 64, 64);


    Phaser.Sprite.call(this, game, x, y, 'playersheet');
this.anAttribute = 'whatever'; this.anotherAttribute = 20;};
Player.prototype = Object.create(Phaser.Sprite.prototype);
Player.prototype.constructor = Player;
```

throws:

> Phaser.Loader - script[Player]: error loading asset from URL resources/js/Player.js

and

> Phaser.Cache.getImage: Key "playersheet" not found in Cache.

main:

in preload

```
game.load.script('Player', 'resources/js/Player.js');
```

in create

```
testPlayer = new Player(game,77,77);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way of preloading assets is by calling the loader inside the `preload()` method of a `Phaser.State` (just like you do with `Player.js`). The state manager will only move past `preload()` after all load calls are executed and all the needed resources are fetched. Yes, it might be inconvenient if you have a lot of assets that you don't want to load at once, but the other way would be to check yourself if the spritesheet has loaded, which might introduce lag in the creation of the `Player` (plus it seems that there isn't a way to check for individual assets, only for the whole queue).

If you still want to load it manually, that's a way to do it (haven't tested it):

```
game.load.spritesheet('playersheet', 'resources/data/foo.png', 64, 64);
game.load.start();
game.load.onLoadComplete.add(function() {
  // do the rest of the stuff here
}, this);
```

... but this way it becomes messy if you need another callback in there, plus it only works if the player spritesheet is the only thing to load at that point.

As for why it doesn't find `Player.js`, you need to supply a path relative to `main.js`, so if they're in the same directory, go with just the filename.

Comment: thanks so much this really helped and is REALLY appreciated

Comment: Sadly this didn't help for me. The image is still not found.